# How to get iBeacon CLBeaconRegion identifier (not uuid)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

It's pretty frustrating to not being able to retrieve identifier from CLBeaconRegion. Here's a simplified example:

```
let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0")!, major: 111, minor: 222, identifier: "NewBeacon")

locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if let beacon = beacons.first {
        print(beacon.identifier) //that
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get "NewBeacon" identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier is associated with the region, you can simply access [`region.identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clregion/1423583-identifier)

Comment: Now I understand that I missed entire region parameter in locationManager. Thank you!